# Multithreaded Music Playing with Pygame in Terminal

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pygame

I am attempting to make a text game and add some music to it and maybe sounds too, however, the "Big and Greatest" answer was Pygame. After testing with it, I found that when you use ANY Pygame function, it stops the current terminal session from printing any more output, this stops the game from continuing.

I first tried the usual...

```
from pygame import *
def some_function():
    mixer.load("music.mp3")
    mixer.music.play(0)

    clock = time.Clock()
    clock.tick(10)
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        clock.tick(10)
    Rest_of_function
```

And of course this does not work because it is a loop and is doing it in order so I next tried...

```
from file_with_music import * #added threading to this file

def main():
    file_with_music.start()
    Rest_of_Function
```

This however did not work as the annoying "Welcome to pygame" popup blocked terminal output again...

SO the next step was to make a new file and...

```
from Main import *
from Intro_Sounds import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Intro_Thread.start() #Intro did not start because pygame popup was somehow called
    Music_Thread.start()
```

Even after putting them both in threads, it still did not work...

As a side note, there is a function built into Main that is meant to execute

```
Music_Thread.join()
Music_Thread.stop()
```

After certain input is met.

The expected result is for it to play music in the background while the terminal continues printing out input and accepting input up until the input that would kill the Music thread is input. Of course, it did not work, and I am at a loss...

How can music be played without freezing the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things I found...

Pygame is not friendly with sound and terminal output, so it won't work.

WxPython no longer has a functional sound module, making it useless.

Other projects are abandoned or OS specific...

However, I found that PyOpenAL actually works, although it can't understand mp3 files or 32bit float wav. Instead of using multithreading I switched to multiprocessing (making a 2000 line script to properly learn how the module works) and now the sound plays (and loops) while allowing terminal output.

TL:DR

PyOpenAL is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

The `pygame.mixer` sadly doesn't have this capability (as far as I know). Use `winsound` instead:

```
import winsound  # only on windows tho...
winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)  # this will play the sound and...
print('I can still print :D')                        # this can still print :D
```

Comment: Probably not... I'll search for some alternatives.

Comment: I'll try as well

Comment: wxPython seemed promising, however it's missing all useful documentation, and they removed all sound modules from the looks of an import....

Answer (score 0):

please try as follow--

```
from pygame import *
def some_function():
    pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    clock = time.Clock()
    clock.tick(10)
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        clock.tick(10)
    Rest_of_function
```